# SQL INNER JOIN comparison isn't an exact comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a SQL query that compares a queued list with a reference list to find information about the items (details) in the queue. The details have numbers (in the example below they are 40, 26, and 26-1).  I added 4 detail 26s and2 detail 40s to the queue but when I run this query:

```
SELECT workingQueue.orderID, workingQueue.toolNum, workingQueue.detailNum, details.detailNum
FROM workingQueue
INNER JOIN details
WHERE workingQueue.toolNum = details.tool
AND workingQueue.detailNum = details.detailNum
```

It gives me a list of those 6 in the queue as well as an instance of detail 26-1 that coincides with each detail 26.  It is like the

```
workingQueue.detailNum = details.detailNum
```

isnt giving an exact comparison.  The detailNum field is a varchar if that helps.  Is there any idea as to what I am doing wrong? Or is this just the nature of the SQL language that has to be worked around somehow?

The output looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: Same output when I do:

```
SELECT workingQueue.orderID, workingQueue.toolNum, workingQueue.detailNum, details.detailNum
FROM workingQueue
INNER JOIN details
ON workingQueue.toolNum = details.tool
AND workingQueue.detailNum = details.detailNum
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the type of columns `workingQueue.detailNum` and `details.detailNum` ? And show us the content of both tables ty :)

Comment: That was the problem.  In the working queue they were the wrong data type (INT instead of VARCHAR).  Stupid mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from your workingQueue and details tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the working queue I had the wrong data type (INT instead of VARCHAR). IT was comparing a number to a string and did the best it could by converting (I guess) the string 26-1 into a number 26. Stupid mistake. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` needs `ON` to specify the join clause :

```
SELECT workingQueue.orderID, workingQueue.toolNum, workingQueue.detailNum,  details.detailNum
FROM workingQueue
     INNER JOIN details
         ON workingQueue.toolNum = details.tool
         AND workingQueue.detailNum = details.detailNum
```

Comment: I made that change and still got the same output